# Identifying Changes to SQL Database Structure Post Install

Tags: sql, database, installation, change-tracking

Sometimes, when installing new vendor development, tables are added, modified, or deleted.  Additionally Stored Procedures are also sometimes added, modified or deleted as well.  Either of these could include content changes (e.g. a new configuration entry added in an existing table).

I'm looking for an effective way to track these changes that happen during the install, as they are not always communicated by the vendor and cause negative downstream impacts.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you could store the results from the different sys tables which contain the database structure. Then after a new release you can write a query in which you FULL OUTER JOIN the old relevant sys tables on the new sys table and keeping only the rows which result in a NULL in either the old sys table or NULL in the new sys table.

A Null in the old sys table means that something was added in the new release or that the value you are joining on has changed.

A NULL in the new sys table means that something was deleted in the new release or that the value you are joining on has changed.

I assume that different SQL versions have something similar to the aforementioned sys tables.

I have made an example using sys.tables. The same would work for columns, schemas, functions, procedures, etc.
[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cd8a91/1/4)

```
CREATE TABLE SysTablesOld (Name varchar(200));
CREATE TABLE DeleteMe (Test int);
CREATE TABLE ChangeMe (Test int);
CREATE TABLE NoChange (Test int);

INSERT INTO SysTablesOld (Name)
SELECT Name
FROM sys.tables;

-- changes in the new release
DROP TABLE DeleteMe;
CREATE TABLE AddMe (Test int);
EXEC sp_rename 'ChangeMe', 'ChangedMe'; 

SELECT 
    old.Name AS Old
  , new.Name AS New
FROM sys.tables AS new
FULL OUTER JOIN SysTablesOld AS old
  ON old.Name = new.Name;
```